# Find Chrome Driver Version Used

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

We have below webdrivermanager version in our pom. But is there anyway you can see/find the version of chromedriver used by it?:-

```
  <webdrivermanager.version>3.8.0</webdrivermanager.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found it from trace while running the tests:-
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 36187
Only local connections are allowed.